# Android Development: Service get killed

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I've got a running service. But when taskmanager kill the Activivty that starts the service the service get killed to.

Why do my service get killed when the taskmanager kill the activity not the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing CommonsWare: if the only reason for your Service to exist was that it was bound to the activity, when that activity is killed there is no longer a reason for the service to exist, hence it could be killed.

(I thinking in bound services in here! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

**Update**

Based on your comment, I see that you are using a "Started" service. In that case I recommend you to implemente the service in a separate class, not as an inner class within the Activity class. This could be what was causing your problem.

Comment: well bascily in the extend activity class i added: startService(this.myService)

Comment: no i have 2 classes, i extend activity and one extend service.

Comment: I think he means this, I'm experiencing sort of the same: He has an Activity, and uses startService() to start his Service. At some point, the Activity gets killed (Force stopping package com.mypackage). The next logcat message shows me that my service has crashed, and the ActivityManager is scheduling its restart, which might or might not happen. Any insight on this?

Comment: What do you see in the logcat? Do you implement the Service as an inner class of the activity?

Comment: Just that, what I said in previous comment, and my Service is a seperate class.

Comment: Could it be that the Android OS simply needed the memory your service was using? I don't see another explanation but without being able to reproduce the problem it's hard to solve it!

Comment: So the problem appeared again. The Activity was closed, and the service kept running. After a while, this came up in the logcat: `07-03 14:45:11.950: INFO/ActivityManager(583): Process com.myapp (pid 7555) has died.
07-03 14:45:11.950: WARN/ActivityManager(583): Scheduling restart of crashed service service com.myapp/.MyService in 14999ms`

Comment: No i dont mean like Android OS running out of Memory. When i use "Kill application my service gets killed to" But like if i kill HTC sense Home the service is still running...

Answer (score 1):

There is no "taskmanager" in Android, at least by that name.

If you are running Android 2.1 or older, third party applications that describe themselves as "task managers" or "task killers" can terminate your entire process, and more besides, which will get rid of your service.

If you are running Android 2.2 or newer, while "task managers" have a somewhat reduced role, the Settings application in the OS allows users to force-stop any application or individual service.

IOW, what you are seeing is perfectly normal and something you need to take into account. Users do not like services running for long stretches of time, unless they perceive value from those services being there. So, for example, a user who kills the service that is playing back music quickly learns not to do that anymore. But, if the user does not know what value your service is adding, and your service is running a lot, expect it to be shut down by the user.

As a result, savvy developers architect their applications to avoid long-running services. For example, if you are checking the Internet for something (e.g., new email) every 15 minutes, rather than have a service running all of the time, use `AlarmManager` to start up your service every 15 minutes, and have that service stop itself once the Internet check is complete. This gives you the same functionality, but you stay out of memory most of the time.

Comment: Sorry i mean taskkiller. because the built in HTC Sense 2.3.3 has a app called taskmanager